# Magento2:I can't the send email to admin after Customer Register

Tags: email, magento2.2.2, customer-registration

I have create the observer when the customer is register to get notification to admin

```
 <event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer name="sendmail_toadmin" instance="Namespace\Module \Observer\SendMailToAdmin"/>
</event>
```

Observer path is app/code/Namespace/Module/Observer/SendMailToAdmin

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SendMailToAdmin implements ObserverInterface
{

const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'trans_email/ident_general/email';
protected $_transportBuilder;
protected $inlineTranslation;
protected $scopeConfig;
protected $storeManager;
protected $_escaper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
) {
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{


    $customer = $observer->getData('customer');

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
    try 
    {
        $error = false;

        $sender = [
            'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer->getFirstName()),
            'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer->getEmail()),
        ];
        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($sender);
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 
        $transport = 
            $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('1') // Send the ID of Email template which is created in Admin panel
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // using frontend area to get the template file
                'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage(); ;
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();


    } 
    catch (\Exception $e) 
    {
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug($e->getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

I got the error

> we cant save the customer

please help me

Comment: Are you sure the observer is firing ? @Magento

Comment: When i click on create account it display message We can't save the customer..when i remove the observer then it work properly

Comment: setTemplateIdentifier('1') provide a valid identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, but maybe the problem is the space in your events.xml file?

It should be: `Namespace\Module\Observer\SendMailToAdmin`

instead of: `Namespace\Module \Observer\SendMailToAdmin`

```
<event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer name="sendmail_toadmin" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\SendMailToAdmin"/> 
</event>
```

At first, I think it's just a typo when you write down your question, but your code work fine for me until I also copy that space into my code, then I can replicate the very same error message you described.